# Raspberry Python Libraries

Tags: gpio, python, rpi.gpio, pwm

I am currently working with a Raspberry Pi (Model B+) and have some experience with Arduino (and it's derivates).

Now, there are *three* Libs for GPIO access with Python for the Pi:

- WiringPi (WiringPi2)
- RPi.GPIO
- RPIO

What are the advantages/disatvantages of each, since I cannot find a comprehensive list.

RPIO (latest update to version 0.10.1 2 years ago according to github) is said to replace RPi.GPIO which is somehow still maintained (latest update to version 0.5.9 2015-01-04). Furthermore, the latest update to WiringPi2 on github is 7 months ago.

More specifically, the RPIO is said to provide better PWM results (among other things, I'm gonna control a servo) than RPi.GPIO which did a good job so far.

I'd like to work with just **one** Python GPIO lib.

**UPDATE:**

I now migrated my whole code to work with the *pigpio* framework which works like a charme.

Comment: It looks like the most used is RPi.GPIO. import RPi.GPIO as GPIO For further instrutions, see [RPi.GPIO Wiki](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Home/)

Comment: related: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85798/19949

Answer (score 3):

I tried RPi.GPIO for a PWM LED strip and found I could not get a stable refresh. You might not notice it so much with a servo but it was very evident with the LEDs. I resigned myself to using hardware for PWM on RPi.

Comment: With RPi.GPIO, LEDs can be dimmed, but the servo was stuttering so I use RPIO for that (RPIO uses DMA to create a nice PWM-signal/square-wave). Currenty working with RPi.GPIO for "regular" GPIO access and RPIO for PWM, since migration isn't complete yet.