# Which is the standard python library for Rpi other than GPIO library?

Tags: python, rpi.gpio

Which python library is best one to use for programming RPI? I want to program RPI zero and Rpi 3 model B+ using python.

I know that there is a GPIO library available for RPI. However, in its readme file, it was mentioned that it is not suitable for time critical applications.

Still, is it the only library available for programming rpi in python? In my application, I may have to use the 1kHz loop. Will it be possible with the GPIO library?

Comment: Consistent timing with microsecond resolution is impossible to implement in a Linux application.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev thanks. what is the solution to get the microsecond resolution timing loop. is there a real time OS available?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev That is not true.  I use microsecond timing on a regular basis on the Pi under Linux.  Linux not being real-time is true but that does not prevent microsecond timing in specific cases, it depends on what you are actually doing.

Comment: @joan Yeah, that's what I meant by *consistent*. Does `nanosleep(1000)` always take 1 microsecond?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev No, all Linux sleeps are a minimum time.  If you use a 4 core Pi it is possible to reserve a core and some people report that gives very good results.  Personally I would use the DMA timing capabilities exposed by (my) pigpio for microsecond timing and above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a pity you didn't originally ask about GPIO libraries.  Your original question made little sense.

There are at least 5 Python GPIO libraries.

They each have their own merits.

See https://elinux.org/RPi_GPIO_Code_Samples#Python for code examples of most.

- [RPi.GPIO](https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/)
- [RPIO.GPIO](https://pythonhosted.org/RPIO/)
- [wiringPi](https://github.com/WiringPi/WiringPi-Python)
- [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html)
- [gpiozero](https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

The RPi.GPIO, pigpio, and gpiozero Python modules are normally pre-installed on full Raspbian images.  gpiozero is the Raspberry Pi foundations preference.